# $1 outputting no characters in regex

Tags: regex

A couple people just recommended removing the curly brackets from ${1}, but that didn't seem to change anything; still getting nothing for $1.

I am trying to put the stuff within parentheses into the value of a src attribute in an img tag:

```
$toc_line =~ s!<inlineFig.*?(\.\./pics/ch09_inline99_*?\.jpg)*?</inlineFig>!<img src="$1" alt="" />!g;
```

The img tags still come out with src="" instead of, eg, src="../pics/ch09_inline99_00".

Thx

*Please add information to your existing question*

**Duplicate:** [Why is $1 empty in my substitution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344460/1-outputting-no-characters-in-regex-output)

Comment: you should continue this in the existing thread, not repost an essential duplicate only without the history

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add dots before the second and third stars.